# Does Google Drive API works exactly with drive which belongs to the account of application's owner?

Tags: google-drive-api

Does Google Drive API works exactly with drive which belongs to the account of application's  owner, or it works with drive of any owner which has been authorized through it ?

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

By using your words `it works with drive of any owner which has been authorized through it`. If you've generated the token through X user which is allowed to administrate your project the Drive in question is the Drive of the "User X"

In other words, your app **works under the OAuth 2.0 Client ID "credentials.json" owner** so you are using the Drive of the Google Cloud Project owner (by default, the google account which enabled the Drive API).

### Explanation

I think you have a misconception about what Authorization and Authentication is on Google Cloud Platform.

- **Authentication**: refers to the process of determining a client's identity.
- **Authorization**: refers to the process of determining what permissions an authenticated user has for different resources.

In other words authentication identifies who you are and authorization determines what you can do.

There are three types of authentication services that Google APIs use:

- **API keys**: secret tokens that are encrypted strings
- **OAuth 2.0 Client IDs**: similar to API keys but can be linked to user accounts or identities, primarily used for accessing user data. These tokens are based on scopes as mentioned above (google account CAN USE some service given the scope)
- **Service Accounts**: Special Google Account that belongs to your application rather than a individual user. your app assumes the identity of this account and users aren't directly involved "unless" you [impersonate a user](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests).

### References

- [IAM Overview](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview)
- [Creating and deleting API keys](https://cloud.google.com/api-keys/docs/create-delete-api-keys)
- [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2)

Comment: As I checked this, It is not so. The API works with google drive, of that user who's authorize through it. And I exactly need that thing, when API will be working only with my google drive, and not with any drives of other users.

Comment: Correct, I apologize I quoted the wrong sentence. I just edited my answer.